# How to access activity information

Tags: android, android-intent

I am Android beginner so please forgive if the question might sound silly. I had an app idea where a youtube video or a web page open on a smartphone could be transferred to the laptop screen by detecting a particular forward phone motion-gesture. But to program something like that, I realized that I need to have access to the browsers web page or the video URL which the youtube app is playing. With some initial research it seems to me that the Android system doesn't keep that piece of information. Am I correct?

The end solution seems to me to code up my own browser or maybe enhance an existing open source one. I looked into the possibility of accessing the temporary files on the phone through my program but the location /data/data seems accessible only to root I guess. Also I intended my app to run as a background service so that I could later expand the idea to other places like transferring and opening PDF file on a laptop etc in a similar fashion. Is there a way around where I can access similar information from a running application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for showing a youtube video , check this one out:
http://code.google.com/p/android-youtube-player/

also , isn't it easier to transfer the url alone to the other device instead of sending the entire video?
you could do this in multiple ways : bluetooth , wifi , qr code ,usb ,  morse , ...  the possibilities are countless .

about accessing other apps data , the app must provide it to you in some way , since all apps are protected from each other (using sandboxing) . for youtube , you can "listen" to youtube urls (via intent filter) for allowing the user to choose your app instead of youtube app (or any other app that listens to it) .

about /data/data , this is correct , only rooted devices can reach it , or your own app if all you do is access your own folder (which is /data/data/YOUR_APP_PACKAGE_NAME) .you can also reach this folder on an emulator .

it's also quite easy to root your device . even novice users can do it via a third party app . here's something that worked for me on both galaxy S and galaxy S2 :
http://www.unlockroot.com/

Comment: Yes I meant sending only the video URL on the wifi network and not the whole video. Also, I agree to the intent filters but what if the user wants to transfer to laptop screen while he is in the midst of reading a web page on the smartphone? The feature which I believe is quiet exciting to have.

Comment: i don't understand . if the user transfers the url to the other device , isn't he going to watch it? it's quite hard to watch something while reading something else. in any way , even if this is what you want , isn't it easier that the other device would fetch the video from the url that the smartphone has sent it , instead of the smartphone download the video and then send it ? it will also be much faster for the end user.

Comment: Sorry, I suppose I am not making myself clear. Let me try again. What I have in mind is, suppose a user is playing a video on a youtube app and suppose he wants to transfer it to the laptop screen. So he makes the gesture which my app (implemented as a background service) identifies and then catches the video URL from the youtube app and then transfer the URL to the laptop which fetches the video from the web using that URL. The web browser is second usage example for my proposed app where the web page address is sent to the laptop on detecting the gesture and the laptop fetches it ina browser

Comment: Both these use cases are independent. I hope I am more clearer now.

Comment: i think it's possible . you can either check the API of the youtube app if there is something that you can hook to , and if there isn't , just do what i've written before (listen to the youtube links intents) and tell the end user to set your app as the default app , which will be like a pipe : each time a youtube intent is sent , your app records it and sends it to the youtube app , while your service listens to the gyro sensor to be able to send the link to the other device. another alternative would be to add an intent filter for sharing the video url (like facebook,twitter,etc...) .

Comment: please let me know if you succeed . it sounds like a cool idea.

Comment: yes why not? if you want and can afford the time, you can cross collaborate. I will keep updating you about whats happening which will help me keep motivated as well. You also seem to be a much better android developer than me. Someone whom I can seek, if and when I run into trouble not far off ;). Let me know and PM me your email id if you want. Thanks.